# Reusable JavaScript Toggle Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, toggle

I'm new to javascript, and I'm attempting to use it to toggle the display of several elements.  I have written a script to toggle a single element, but my actual site contains several elements over several different pages, so I'd like to write a single function that I can reuse on many different elements.

An example page might be:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some | Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="pepper" onclick="changeDisplay('greendiv')">Click Here</h1>
<div id="greendiv" style="height:200px; width:200px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeDisplay('id') {
        var styleState = document.getElementById('id');
    var divState = document.getComputedStyle('id').display;
    if (divState == 'none') {
        styleState.style.display = 'block';
    } else if (divState == 'block') {
        styleState.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

only on the actual site, I put a reference to the external script file containing the code in the `<head>` tag so I could use the same script on lots of pages.  In case it's not obvious from the code, the intent is for me to be able to click the `<h1>` tag to make the `<div>` disappear and reappear.  I don't know jQuery, although I recently got a book on it, I just haven't had time to start reading, but I'll bet it would make it a whole lot simpler.

I imagine it's something really simple, it's always the really simple stuff that throws me off...

If someone could explain the error in my code, I would *really* appreciate it.

Whoops, left out the actual problem:  The code doesn't do anything.  When I click the `<h1>` element, nothing happens, not even an alert box.

Comment: `changeDisplay('id')` should be `changeDisplay(id)`. Variables don't have any quotes around them. Same thing for `document.getElementById`, and divState should be equal to `styleState.style.display`.

Comment: @Bucky24 - Ah. Thank you ever so much!

Comment: You would be better off using CSS to toggle visibility by adding/modifying the class of the elements. This way the JavaScript doesn't hard code the style.

Answer (score 1):

(Adding a proper answer rather then leaving it as a comment)

1) `changeDisplay('id')` should be `changeDisplay(id)`. Variables don't have any quotes around them. Same thing for `document.getElementById`

2) divState should be equal to `styleState.style.display`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this very simple:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/